# Switch views after a specified time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently developing a landscape app that I would like to have a launch image in. Since launch images do not work in landscape, I want to make my launch image a view, and after about 5 seconds after this view is shown when the app launches, the view will switch to the original first view of the app. How do I do this? I am using storyboards.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using asset catalogs for the launch image and also not using asset catalogs. Both did not work. Then I made a test app. When the only box checked off was portrait the launch image showed perfectly. However when I only checked off landscape left and right it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a delay to set off a segue programmatically.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self performSelector:@selector(enterthegame) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

-(void)enterthegame{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"tothegame" sender: self];
}
```

Just make sure that you have a segue and its identifier matches your code. The button the the segue is connected to can be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a custom view in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

```
UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.png"]];
[[yourFirstViewController view] addSubview:imageView];
[[yourFirstViewController view] bringSubviewToFront:imageView];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// Fade out the image
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window 
                  duration:1.0f 
                   options:nil
                animations:^(void)
{ 
    imageView.alpha=0.0f;
} 
                completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "yourFirstViewController" like the name of the view controller that will appear after the image is shown?

Comment: That's literally first view controller that you show. The initial view controller.

Comment: Im getting a warning with nil, and a warning and error with both of the yourFirstViewController and also the "view" after it. I still do not know what to put in your first view controller

Comment: The view error is "class method +view not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: The nil error is: "incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void*' to parameter of type 'UIViewAnimationOptions'

Comment: Of course you are getting this errors. You have to modify my code to suit your case. Specify your initial view controller etc.

Comment: I did that but what do I do with nil and view